# How to select desired parent of the clicked element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have  a while loop in which I am fetching posts of user's friend now  I have a react column in which user can choose his reaction emoji and I want to hide the div with class react2 when any reaction is clicked now I am unable to choose the parent div that is react2 of the clicked input type. this is my code :

```
<div class="float2">
  <div class="react2" id="react2" data-rowid="<?php echo $pixid?>"><?php
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM gormint where post_id = $pixid and user_id= $id3";
$fire2 = mysqli_query($con,$query2) or die("can not fetch data from database ".mysqli_error($con));
$query3 = "SELECT * FROM bhai where post_id = $pixid and user_id= $id3";
$fire3 = mysqli_query($con,$query3) or die("can not fetch data from database ".mysqli_error($con));
$query4 = "SELECT * FROM famer where post_id = $pixid and user_id= $id3";
$fire4 = mysqli_query($con,$query4) or die("can not fetch data from database ".mysqli_error($con));
$query5 = "SELECT * FROM muskan where post_id = $pixid and user_id= $id3";
$fire5 = mysqli_query($con,$query5) or die("can not fetch data from database ".mysqli_error($con));
if (mysqli_num_rows($fire2)>0) {
  echo "<img src='gormint.jpg' class='gormint2' style='width:30px; height:30px;'  >";
}elseif (mysqli_num_rows($fire3)>0) {
  echo "<img src='bhai.jpg' class='bhai2' style='width:30px; height:30px;'>";
}elseif (mysqli_num_rows($fire4)>0) {
  echo "<img src='famer.jpg' class='bhai2' style='width:30px; height:30px;'>";
}elseif (mysqli_num_rows($fire5)>0) {
  echo "<img src='bancho.jpg' class='bhai2' style='width:30px; height:30px;'>";
} else{
  echo "<img src='wink.png' class='wink2' style='width:30px; height:30px;'>";
}?>
</div>

<div class="flipClass" style="display: flex;" data-rowid="<?php echo $pixid?>" id="flip">react</div>


<div class="panelClass" style="" id="panel" data-rowid="<?php echo $pixid?>"> 
  <input type="image" onclick="PlaySound2()" id="display" data-value="<?php echo $users['id'];?>"  src="gormint2.jpg" class="close2 display gormint animated bounceIn " >


              </div>

              </div>
```

And this is my script :

```
$(document).on('click','.display',function(){


    var value=$(this).attr('data-value');
    $panelClass = $(this).parent().parent().parent().attr('id');
    $.ajax({url:"reaction.php?pollid="+value,cache:false,
      success:function(){

       $panelClass.fadeOut();

    }});
});
```

Now when I click on reaction button the react2 div does not fade out what am I doing wrong???

Comment: `desired parent` or just `parent` ?

Comment: parent with class react2 @C2486

Comment: You can use [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) - jquery function that selects first parent with given selector.

Comment: Avoid using the `$` when possible in Javascript (if your using PHP for server side ).  It confuses people like me.

Comment: did you try with id `#display` as `$(document).on('click','#display',function(){` instead class `.display` ?

Comment: yes i tried it @C2486

Comment: tried closest function but no luck @Goran.it

Comment: share the html generated and put live snippet here ?

Comment: `$(this).closest('.react2')` , shouldn't be that hard.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix : I think he wanted to get this id by `.attr('id');`

Comment: So is it a surprise this doesn't work then

Answer (score 1):

The reason it doesn't work is your getting the id. So you basically are trying to do this (assuming `parent().parent()` stuff works)

```
$panelClass = $(this).parent().parent().parent().attr('id');
//$panelClass = 'react2'
$.ajax({url:"reaction.php?pollid="+value,cache:false,
  success:function(){

   $panelClass.fadeOut();
  // or "react2".fadeOut();

}});
```

In English, `.attr('id')` returns a string, then you call fade out on it.  Basically your calling `fadeOut()` on a string and not a Dom Element, and a string has no concept of that function.  That's assuming your event handler even fires (see below).

For example(incorrect)

```js
$('input[name="test"]').click(function(){
      
       //this is a string (the ID) nothing to do with a class
      $panelClass = $(this).parent().parent().parent().attr('id');

      //throws JS error
      $panelClass.fadeOut();
      
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="react2" id="react2" >
  <div>
     <div>
          <input type="button" name="test" value="click here" >
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you have to keep that `parent()...` stuff, either remove the `attr` call or wrap the resulting ID `$('#'+$panelClass).fadeOut();` which looks awful, besides doing an additional DOM lookup.

For example(correct)

```js
$('input[name="test"]').click(function(){
      
       //this is a string (the ID) nothing to do with a class
      $panelClass = $(this).parent().parent().parent(); //no attr call

      //throws JS error
      $panelClass.fadeOut();
      
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="react2" id="react2" >
  <div>
     <div>
          <input type="button" name="test" value="click here" >
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Honestly I don't know what is wrong with doing something like this `$(this).closest('.react2').fadeOut();`.

For example (better, wont brake if you add another nested div):

```js
$('input[name="test"]').click(function(){          
      $(this).closest('.react2').fadeOut();        
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="react2" id="react2" >
  <div>
     <div>
          <input type="button" name="test" value="click here" >
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Using closest is cleaner (less code), more specific, and it won't break if you happen to need another element to wrap the input in.  With parent if you add another wrapping element, such as a `<label>` you have to add another `parent()` call in there.

**Other things, beyond the current issue**

**1** I'm not even sure your event handler is being triggered because you assigned it to a class and you have an id in the DoM.

```
<input type="image" onclick="PlaySound2()" id="display" .. //this is an id
$(document).on('click','.display',function(){ //this is a class
  ...
```

Should be:

```
  $(document).on('click','#display',function(){
  //Or
  <input type="image" onclick="PlaySound2()" class="display" ..
```

Depending on if it's unique in the document.  But either way you have to use a class on both or an ID on both.

**2** Avoid using the `$` in your Javascript variables, it's just a bad idea to use them if you don't have to when your using PHP.  It can make the code confusing to look at.  If they are in the wrong place PHP could think they are for Him.

**3** These queries (I can't look at them)

```
 $query2 = "SELECT * FROM gormint where post_id = $pixid and user_id= $id3";
 $fire2 = mysqli_query($con,$query2) or die("can not fetch data from database ".mysqli_error($con));
 $query3 = "SELECT * FROM bhai where post_id = $pixid and user_id= $id3";
 $fire3 = mysqli_query($con,$query3) or die("can not fetch data from database ".mysqli_error($con));

 ....

if(mysqli_num_rows($fire2)>0) {
  echo "<img src='gormint.jpg' class='gormint2' style='width:30px; height:30px;'  >";
 }elseif (mysqli_num_rows($fire3)>0) {
   echo "<img src='bhai.jpg' class='bhai2' style='width:30px; height:30px;'>";
 }elseif(....
```

Your running 4 queries, then because you use a single conditional block only the results of one of them matter.  Consider using a Join, or restructuring your code.  Your paying a lot of performance for network traffic and then just basically throwing the data away.

Just to be clear if `if(mysqli_num_rows($fire2)>0) {` passes none of the other conditions are evaluated, even though you did the queries for them.  At  the very least add `LIMIT 1` to them.

Comment: dude i am really confused so what should i do to my code eventually??

Comment: i noticed one thing that when i use  $(this).fadeOut()  nothing happens but when i use $('.react2').fadeOut() then every element with react2 class fades out  so i think that $(this) is not working @ArtisticPheonix

Comment: `For example(correct)` There I marked it, I don't know what else to tell you.

Comment: `i noticed one thing that when i use $(this).fadeOut()` - In javascript what `this` means depends on your current scope.  For example if you use this in a callback, it means the callback, if you use it in a `$.each` inside the callback it means the `$.each`, if you use it in the callback of AJAX, it refers to that function.  Therefor without knowing where you used that, in what context, it's meaningless to me.

Comment: Another example would be in ajax callback you cant do `$(this).fadeOut()` because your telling the success handler `success : function(){ .. }`  to fadeout.  Basically your telling `function()` to fadeout, not a Dom element.  When you store the Dom Element in a variable above the Ajax callback, and use that inside such as this variable `$panelClass` then it knows what its supposed to be.